# Issues with PyQt4 + SIP on Windows 10: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SIP (from versions: )

Tags: python, pip, pyqt4, python-sip

I have been trying to install SIP and PyQt4 + SIP for a while now under windows 10 in a Virtual env (legacy project so was done in PyQt4). I started in PyCharm using the package manager. I also tried command line.

```
    C:\Users\jspada>pip install SIP
Collecting SIP
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SIP (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for SIP

C:\Users\jspada>pip install PyQt4
Collecting PyQt4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

Is this because there are no builds out there for SIP and PyQt4? PyQt4 maybe because it is a bit legacy but I would think SIP would work.

Comment: Usually this means there isn't  release available for your python version. Which python are you using and is it vanilla python or from a distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the project is so old I guess it's Python 2.7. SIP doesn't have binaries at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP) for python less than 3.5 and [PyQt4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt4) doesn't provide binaries at all.

You have to download sources for [SIP](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) and [PyQt4](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and compile it yourself.

You can find some precompiled packages at [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4).