# Python GUI to display PDF file with options

Tags: python, user-interface, pdf

I'm having the following issue and I would be really grateful for any advice.

**I'm trying to create Python Desktop App which will be able to display PDF file and in the same application windows will show some options which user will be able to edit.**

My question is, is it possible? And which Python GUI I should use for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Remember to check my answer as correct, if it was useful and solved your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use **PyQT**. As a GUI Toolkit, it allows you to build your interface based on the Qt application Framework. It has a good collection of GUI Widgets which you can use, as well as the possibility to create your own. It´s also included QT Designer for visual GUI design.
For more Information:

- https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro

According to your question, PyQT provides some possibilities to display PDFs. One of them is to use the following library for PyQT: [Poppler](https://github.com/danigm/poppler)

The same library offers different manipulation tools for PDFs. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thank for your advice, I was trying to do this, but PyQt requires sip to be installed before, I've installed sip==4.19.8 but when I'm trying to instal PyQt it is showing error that the sip==4.19.12 is required. I was trying to reinstall it but when I'm trying to install required version of sip the following error shows up: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip==4.19.12 (from versions: 4.19, 4.19.1, 4.19.2, 4.19.3, 4.19.4, 4.19.5, 4.19.6, 4.19.7, 4.19.8).

Comment: Try to make a clean installation by removing and installing it again. Like always in Ubuntu different installation options are provided, just check it out: [link](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download).

Comment: Maybe is a compatibility issue as well with the version of Python that you have and the PyQT version that you are trying to install. This could help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686198/issues-with-pyqt4-sip-on-windows-10-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-t)